# Debian 8(Jessie) started before DHCP server results in no network connection

Tags: debian, networking, dhcp

Recently we got a power outage and our debian 8 Raspberry Pi did not reconnect to the internet.

We noticed that our DHCP server was very slow to start > 5 min. In this time the Pi was already up and running, but without connection to the internet. 30 minutes later and still no attempt to make a connection to the internet, no entries from dhclient in syslog either.

If we just do `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0`, it's fixed, but that's kind of hard when the device is somewhere remote and you rely on the interent to connect to it.

Our `/etc/network/interfaces` is very simple:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Are there any solutions to this, other than writing a script that just constantly checks every x minutes if it can ping 8.8.8.8 and if it can't runs `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0`?

Answer (score 2):

If a host configured to use DHCP for IP address assignment is unable to contact a DHCP server, it will automatically configure itself for an address in the 169.254.0.0/16 CIDR block.  Naturally, this will not work for anything other than communicating with other hosts in the same state.  However, these self-assigned quasi leases have a short duration (often no more than five minutes) after which the host will attempt again to contact a DHCP server for configuration.  All you need to do is wait a short while and your device will be correctly set up as normal on the network.

Comment: This does not seem to happen on our Jessie, we keep getting this in the logging: `Oct 18 06:33:58 office2 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67` `Oct 18 06:33:58 office2 dhclient: send_packet: Network is unreachable` `Oct 18 06:34:14 office2 dhclient: send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address`. 192.168.0.1 is the IP address of the dhcp server (that is currently without power). This just keeps repeating itself for hours and the dhclient.leases file is empty and there is no IP address configured on eth0.